# How do I categorize documents by using a specialized taxonomy in NLTK?

Tags: python, rake, classification, nltk

I am stuck with a problem that I cannot find a solution anywhere on google. I have a specialized taxonomy with 3 levels. 
Ex.

1. Level 1 food,
2. level 2 refrigerated,
3. level 3 ice cream.

I am trying to categorize many documents based on this taxonomy.

Do I need to use NLTK or RAKE to extract keywords and then map it to the categories? Or am I completely wrong on the logic here? What do I need to do to map the documents to my taxonomy?

Comment: What part of training a classifier can you "not find a solution" to? If you worry about the multiple levels, train one for the top level and one for each subgroup at each level, to be used depending on the previous decision. (However, I can't say if this would improve performance over a single classifier; you should test.)

Comment: My question is that I have a list of words in a word file or csv, and I have a list of text without tags. How can I connect the two? What do I use to see which document is closest to which word on my list?

Comment: There is no single, easy way to do this. You can try a simple heuristic which looks for matches between the documents and the taxonomy entries, or you train a supervised classifier... I'm sure there are many more possible approaches, and it's hard to tell what works best without trying. However, I'm afraid your question is too broad for Stack Overflow.